# How to make sure that props is update before its being accessed in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

My React js code given below is intended to populate or change the input's initial value on changing the value of cid input (with triggering onBlur), but the values get populated or changed only after triggering the onBlur twice. Help me to identify where I am making mistake. The code is as given below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, Select } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addParticipant, updateParticipant, fetchParticpant } from './actions';

const { Option } = Select;
class CustomParticipantForm extends Component {
    state = {
        confirmDirty: false,
        participantID: null,
        requestType: 'post',
        form_data: {
            identity_no: null,
            name: null,
            email: null,
            gender: null,
        }
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.data !== null) {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                form_data: {
                    ...this.state.form_data,
                    cid: this.props.data.cid,
                    name: this.props.data.name,
                    email: this.props.data.email,
                    gender: this.props.data.gender,
                }
            })
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (event, postType, participantID) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll(async (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                switch (postType) {
                    case 'post':
                        await this.props.addParticipant(values)
                        if (this.props.userError == null)
                            this.props.history.push('/create');
                        break;
                    case 'put':
                        await this.props.updateParticipant(values, participantID)
                        if (this.props.userError == null)
                            this.props.history.push(`/participant/${participantID}`);
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log('default')
                }
            }
        });
    };

    handleConfirmBlur = e => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value });
    };

    handleChange = () => {
        this.setState(
            {
                ...this.state,
                formChanged: true
            }
        )
    }
    getParticipantWithCID = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target
        const { fetchParticpant } = this.props

        fetchParticpant(value) 

        if (this.props.stateParticipantData.length === 1) { //this line gets executed before the above line function call
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                form_data: {
                    ...this.state.form_data,
                    cid: this.props.stateParticipantData[0].cid,
                    name: this.props.stateParticipantData[0].name,
                    email: this.props.stateParticipantData[0].email,
                    gender: this.props.stateParticipantData[0].gender
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                requestType: 'post',
                participantID: null,
                form_data: {
                    cid: value,
                    name: null,
                    email: null,
                    gender: null
                }
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        const formItemLayout =
            this.props.formLayout === 'horizontal'
                ? {
                    labelCol: { span: 6 },
                    wrapperCol: { span: 14 },
                }
                : null;
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        const prefixSelector = getFieldDecorator('prefix', {
            initialValue: '975',
        })(
            <Select style={{ width: 80 }}>
                <Option value="975">+975</Option>
            </Select>,
        );

        return (
            <Form
                layout={this.props.formLayout}
                autoComplete="off"
                onSubmit={event => this.handleSubmit(event,
                    this.state.requestType,
                    this.state.participantID
                )}
            >
                <Form.Item label="CID No." {...formItemLayout} extra="Please enter Alumni's CID ">
                    {getFieldDecorator('cid', {
                        initialValue: this.state.form_data.cid,
                        rules: [
                            {
                                required: true, message: "Alumni's CID is required!",
                                numeric: {
                                    message: "Please Provide valid CID No."
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                    })(
                        <Input type="text" onBlur={this.getParticipantWithCID} />,
                    )}
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="Name" {...formItemLayout} extra="Please enter user's full name">
                    {getFieldDecorator('name', {
                        initialValue: this.state.form_data.name,
                        rules: [
                            {
                                required: true,
                                message: "Participant's full name is required!"
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'string',
                                message: "Participant's full name must be string!"
                            },
                        ],
                    })(
                        <Input type="text" />,
                    )}
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="Gender" {...formItemLayout} extra="Please select Gender">
                    {getFieldDecorator('gender', {
                        initialValue: this.state.form_data.gender,
                        rules: [
                            {
                                required: true, message: "Gender is required!"
                            },
                        ],
                    })(
                        <Select placeholder="Select Gender" >
                            <Option value="Male">Male</Option>
                            <Option value="Female">Female</Option>
                        </Select>,
                    )}
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="Email" {...formItemLayout} extra="Please enter user's email address">
                    {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                        initialValue: this.state.form_data.email,
                        rules: [
                            {
                                required: true, message: "Email address is required!"
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'email', message: 'The input is not a valid email address!'
                            },
                        ],
                    })(
                        <Input type="email" />,
                    )}
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button
                        type="primary"
                        htmlType="submit"
                    >
                        {this.props.btnText}
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form >
        );
    }
}

const ParticipantForm = Form.create()(CustomParticipantForm);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        stateParticipantData: state.participant
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addParticipant: (data) => dispatch(addParticipant(data)),
        updateParticipant: (data, participantID) => dispatch(updateParticipant(data, participantID)),
        fetchParticpant: (cid) => dispatch(fetchParticpant(cid))
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ParticipantForm);
```

Comment: Tell us what is the error ? and what should help you with ?

Comment: triggering onBlur of cid input the rest of the input value should be update but it does not get updated. It gets update only on triggering onBlur  twice.